# stripping off numbers and alphabetics in perl

Tags: perl

I have an input variable, say `$a`. `$a` can be either number or string or mix of both.

My question is how can I strip off the variable to separate numeric digits and alphabetic characters?

Example;

```
$a can be 'AB9'
```

Here I should be able to store 'AB' in one variable and '9' in other.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this version, it works with 1 or more numeric and alphabetic characters in a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = '11a';                           

my (@digits, @alphabetics);

while ($var =~ /([a-zA-Z]+)/g) {

    push @alphabetics, $1;
}   

while ($var =~ /(\d+)/g) {

    push @digits, $1;
}   

print Dumper(\@alphabetics);
print Dumper(\@digits);
```

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot:)
There is a typo while declaring array digit.
declared as `@digit` instead of `@digits`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to express it very shortly:

```
my ($digits) = $input =~ /(\d+)/;
my ($alpha)  = $input =~ /([a-z]+)/i;

say 'digits:     ' . ($digits // 'none');
say 'non-digits: ' . ($alpha // 'none');
```

It's important to use the match operator in list context here, otherwise it would return if the match succeeded.

If you want to get *all* occurrences in the input string, simply change the scalar variables in list context to proper arrays:

```
my @digits = $input =~ /(\d+)/g;
my @alpha  = $input =~ /([a-z]+)/gi;

say 'digits:     ' . join ', ' => @digits;
say 'non-digits: ' . join ', ' => @alpha;
```

For `my $input = '42AB17C'`, the output is

```
digits: 42, 17
non-digits: AB, C
```